# What is this? Part of my doorbell chime?

Tags: wiring, doorbell

What is this? It's inside a closet up high on the wall. On the other side of the wall is my doorbell chime but they don't line up, they're a few inches off. Is this part of it or something else?

it looks like there's a metal circle part with a metal box on it, that has a red and black wire attached

[image: it looks like there's a metal circle part with a metal box on it, that has a red and black wire attached]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the transformer that powers the doorbell.

It takes 120 volts and turns it into around 12 to 18 volt DC.

Doorbells do not need much power and is quite a bit better than having 120 volts in the rain if something happens.